# Azure logic app Action to run the pipeline in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-logic-apps

I created an Azure logic app for running my actions from my application.

so my requirement is to upload the blob to the shared folder from Azure blob.
for that my team is created  azure data factory pipeline,
so from the logic app designer I am running the trigger when the blob is added or modified, I need to run the pipeline from the azure data factory,
while running the trigger, the trigger is fired successfully but it is running at the blob only it is not going to the second action.
can you please give me the guidance how should I resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure data-factory provides the option of azure blob trigger which will work automatically. When new blob gets added your pipeline will run.

[image]

[Data Factory Event Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)

In this case you don't need separate logic app for the triggering event.